# System.TypeInitializationException on setting a static public variable

Tags: c#, console-application

In the same namespace I have these two functions

```
public static class DAL
{
    public static bool SHOWMESSAGES = false;
    private static StreamWriter logger = new StreamWriter(logLocation); // line 4
}


class testmain
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DAL.SHOWMESSAGES = true; //line 5
    }
}
```

If I run this code I will get a "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred". What could be causing this?

Comment: That code in isolation won't exhibit that problem. Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the same problem. What is the message of the exception?

Comment: Please also include the full exception details, including message and stack-trace.

Comment: Again, you must post a [mcve], until you do at best we will be guessing as to what the problem is. Your edit introduces a logger, perhaps the construction of this logger is failing? We simply cannot know until you post a [mcve], or more details, such as the message of the exception, the InnerException, etc.

Comment: Initializing a StreamWriter is always risky, it bombs if *logLocation* is not a valid path.  With pretty good odds that the variable (?) is not initialized.  Don't do that.

Comment: When you first reference static class (DAL in this case), it will get initialized, so static constructor will be run and static fields will be initialized. If some of this will throw exception (for example, when you initialize your logger variable referencing logLocation, which might be null at this point) - it will result in TypeInitializationException you observe.

Comment: This is the minimal and complete example as just having this code produces the error for me. Thanks Evk, I will check with that.

Comment: If that is a complete example it should fail to compile as there is no variable `logLocation` anywhere except as an expression.

Comment: That is a string, Evk gave me enough to find the answer, StreamWriter requires a file to write to and not a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, types are not initialized at application startup but when you access the type for the first time. In your case it is probably at line 5: `DAL.SHOWMESSAGES = true;`

before this statement is executed, `DAL` class must be initialized. Static constructor is executed and all the static field are set to their default value. If this fails, you get `TypeInitializationException`.

I would recommend you to avoid static constructors and static field with default value, e.g. `private static _someField = new SomeClass();`

I your case it could look like this:

```
public static class DAL
{
    public static bool SHOWMESSAGES = false;
    private static StreamWriter logger;
    public static void Initialize() 
    {
        logger = new StreamWriter(....);
    }
}
```

or even better, avoid static class entirely:

```
public class DAL
{
    public bool ShowMessages { get; set; }
    private StreamWriter logger;
    public DAL() 
    {
        logger = new StreamWriter(....);
    }
}

class testmain
{
    static DAL dal;
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dal = new DAL();
        dal.ShowMessages = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the code as posted does not fail like this so while the general gist of what the problem is is correct, it doesn't really answer the question as to "why does this code fail like this". The "answer" is, it doesn't.

Comment: I'm trying to help. These types of errors are easy to find once they are understood. I don't need exact code in order to say what's done wrong